# How to map entities with @EmbeddedId?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone know how to fix the mapping of entities?

Error is

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Column name ID of
>   com.test.TableAa not found in JoinColumns.referencedColumnName.

**TableAa entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_AA")
public class TableAa {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableAaPk pk;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String last_name;
    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@JoinColumns({
    //@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    //@JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false) })       
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableAa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TableBb> tableBbList;
}
```

**TableAaPk composite key**

```
@Embeddable
public class TableAaPk implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private String accountNumber;
}
```

**TableBb entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_BB")
public class TableBb {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableBbPk pk;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String last_name;
}
```

**TableBbPk composite key**

```
@Embeddable
public class TableBbPk implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private String accountNumber;
    @Column(name="CODE")
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false) }) 
    private TableAa tableAa;
}
```

Comment: Format your code, please

Answer (score 0):

In your TAbleAa you should have your OneToMany mapping as follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.tableAa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<TableBb> tableBbList;
```

You reference through the embeddable which name is `pk`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_BB")
public class TableBb {
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableBbPk pk;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String last_name;

    // I think the solution is to add the relation @ManyToOne which mapped by in the other side
    @ManyToOne // because u refere to this name (tableAa) in @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableAa"...) in TableAa entity
    private TableAa tableAa;
}
```